# How to do dependency injection in multiple controller in a single step

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm using ionic1 and I have multiple controller each one is for different page.
Consider the following injections:

```
.controller('login', function($scope, $http, $location, $state,$rootScope , auth,$timeout)
.controller('Home', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state,$location, $ionicNavBarDelegate, $timeout, auth, getData)
```

So on I have about 10 of them.
Most of the injections are common to all the controllers such as `$scope,$rootScope` and few others.
So I want to know if there is a one liner to inject all the dependencies in one go.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a factory which returns some of the most used dependencies.

Something like this:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('common', common);

common.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$http', '$state'];

function common($rootScope, $http, $state) {
  var service = {
    $rootScope: $rootScope,
    $http: $http,
    $state: $state
  };

  return service;
}
```

then you just need to include the `common` service in your controller and use it like this: `common.$rootScope`.

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**
 As @estus said in the comments, with `$scope` it would fail because `$scope` is a local dependency and not available in services/factories. This should not be an issue since I would recommend to avoid `$scope` as far as possible (use controllerAs syntax)

Comment: It will fail, because `$scope` is local controller dependency, while the question is about how to get rid of repeated '$scope' (no doubt, it's the most repeated dep).

Answer (score 1):

Injecting *all dependencies* contradicts the concept of dependency injection (besides the fact that controllers can have local dependencies). A dependency is what a controller *depends* on.

If there are several controllers that have matching dependencies, they can inherit base controller. If child controllers should have their own dependencies, this can be done with base class that automatically assigns dependencies to controller instance. Controller inheritance works best with ES6 classes:

```
class BaseController {
  static get $inject() {
    return ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout'];
  }

  constructor(...deps) {
    this.constructor.$inject.forEach((depName, i) => {
      this[depName] = deps[i];
    });
  }
}


class SomeController extends BaseController {
  static get $inject() {
    return [...super.$inject, 'some'];
  }

  constructor(...deps) {
    super(...deps);
    ...
  }
}

app.controller('SomeController', SomeController);
```

Comment: Is ES6 supported in the ionic 1 environment ?

Comment: I was looking for a one liner but I guess the old way is better then the ES6 method you are suggesting

Comment: It doesn't depend on Ionic but on your target platforms, basically Android 5+ and iOS 9+, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class . ES6 classes are syntactic sugar and listed for illustrative purposes. It's possible to do inheritance in ES5 but it will involve considerably more code that is harder to comprehend. So yes, most times the 'old way' is simpler and does the job. Notice that you need to annotate services and repeat the list of deps, that's where DRY controller classes may be shorter and cleaner.